# I want to recreate array from original array using for loop and getting following error

Tags: arrays, swift

Error at: newArray.insert((newEven), at:index) Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'newArray' is a 'let' constant.

```
var numberArray = [4,7,3,5,45,225,95]
var newArray = [Int] ()

func newInt(newEven: Int, newArray: [Int]) -> Int {
     for newEven in numberArray{
         var index = 0
         index += 1
         if newEven == 0 {
            newArray.insert((newEven), at:index)
         }
         return newEven
     }
 }
print(newArray)
}
```

Comment: Please mention programming language you are using

Comment: Swift language.

Comment: Hmm… what is your code trying to do? It looks like you code might not be doing what you think it is doing. Can you explain what the newInt function is doing?

Comment: actually i am beginner, so i want to create new array from existing array using for in

Comment: Parameters are constants by default. Consider that `newArray` in the function refers to the (local) parameter which has a higher priority than the (global) property `newArray`. And it's unclear what the function is supposed to do. It doesn't even compile because a return value after the loop is missing.

Comment: I feel like your code will only ever create an array of zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because as newArray it is taking and array from function. Change variable name as below and it will work.

```
var numberArray = [4,7,3,5,45,225,95]
var finalArray : [Int] = [Int] ()

func newInt(newEven: Int, newArray: [Int]) -> Int {
     for newEven in numberArray{
         var index = 0
         index += 1
         if newEven == 0 {
            finalArray.insert((newEven), at:index)
         }
         return newEven
     }
 }
print(finalArray)
}
```